# How to use function in settimeout for milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use an ajax call to get the value of timer from the server. And I have to use that value for timeout in setTimeout() method. How to use functions instead of an actual value.

Here is my code:

```
if(isStopped) {
   setTimeout(stopLoading, getTimerValue());
   console.log("Stopped loading image");
}
```

`getTimerValue()` is my ajax call to the server. It works fine if I use an value like 5000 instead of the function. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Update - Solved:
There was an issue with my ajax call. It was returning undefined. After adding callback option, it works fine.

Comment: please see the timeout function the first parameter have to be a `function` and 2nd one should be `miliseconds`
`setTimeout(function, milliseconds,)`
so what is ur `getTimerValue` returns ?

Comment: It returns an integer like 2500

Comment: can u plz provide that function both `stopLoading` and 'getTimerValue'

Comment: you have to make sure  **return value** of `getTimerValue`.

Comment: can you please share a piece of code with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example.

```js
var isStopped = true;

function getTimerValue() {
  return 5000;
}

function stopLoading() {
  console.log('ok')
}

if(isStopped) {
   setTimeout(stopLoading, getTimerValue());
   console.log("Stopped loading image");
}
```

As i set `isStopped` to `true` so its insert the if condition then its set the `setTimeout` function. but as i set it to execute it after `5000` so it will wait in the mean time it will execute the next line `console.log("Stopped loading image");` and the after `5000` it prints `ok`
Hope This will help